# is it possible in cakephp to access directory outside of app

Tags: cakephp

I want to access folder outside the app directory for different web application

my folder structure is like

```
/public_html/app
/public_html/application1
/public_html/application2
```

Url I want is like mydomain.com for app

mydomain.com/application1 for application1

mydomain.com/application2 for application2

Comment: Keep you directory in vendors folders and you can access it by importing it in your controller, OR you can keep the folder in webroot.

Comment: Cartina I dont want to access it in my cake app.but from browser I want to access my app located out side of app.right now I can b'coz of cake's htaccess

Comment: ok. Suppose I have a url say example.com and I want to access a folder called beta, I can keep it in app/webroot/beta, and access it like http://example.com/beta/

Comment: Another way is to create a subdomain like http://beta.example.com in you CPanel and you can access it

Comment: Cartina I know both of above options but want something else like any htaccess code or any other option,thanks

Comment: you mean you want to keep the folder at root with app folder and access it?

Comment: yes,exactly i want to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing this `RewriteRule ^(application1|application2)($|/) - [L]` before the other cakephp rules, in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

### Link in the webroot

One very simply approach to make those applications accessible - is to link them in the webroot:

```
$ cd /public_html/app/webroot
$ ln -s ../../application1 .
$ ln -s ../../application2 .
```

Note that the *webroot* not the app should be the document root, i.e. `mydomain.com` should map to `/public_html/app/webroot` in the example in the question.